# Django postgresql postgis incorrect spatial lookup

Tags: django, postgresql, django-models, postgis

I have the following model:

```
class Item(Model):
    lat_lng = PointField(geography=True, null=True)

Item.objects.create(lat_lng=Point(-95.864468, 36.075450))
bbox1 = (-168.3984375, 25.16517336866393, -52.03125, 75.32002523220804)
bbox2 = (-145.1953125, 25.16517336866393, -52.03125, 63.07486569058663)
```

`bbox1` contains `bbox2`, but `Item.objects.filter(lat_lng__coveredby=Polygon.from_bbox(bbox1))` doesn't return the item, while `Item.objects.filter(lat_lng__coveredby=Polygon.from_bbox(bbox2))` returns it.

Am I missing something?

**UPDATE:**

If I remove `geographic=True`, then everything works. What does this flag stands for?

Answer (score 1):

When using `geography`, great circle arcs are used instead of straight lines. This remains true for the lines connecting the bounding box corners.

The premise that box1 contains box2 is false. They may intersect, but one is not wholly contained in the other.

Box1 is wider than box 2, so its southern boundary, represented as a great circle arc, will go norther than box 2 boundary, and therefore the point is located south of box 1 but within box 2.

Comment: so, I need to use geography=False for checking distance and coveredby?

Comment: not necessarily... this decision is yours and depends on your data and goals. You just must be aware of the great circle arcs vs straight lines, both have their uses. You can google `geometry vs geography` to get more information

Comment: if a have a boundingbox and a latitude-longitude point, how do I check whether the point is inside the circle?

Comment: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/contrib/gis/

Comment: I've seen the docs, but there is no relevant example.

Comment: I can't understand in what situations geography=True is used, if not for latitude/longitude?

Comment: You can start [here](https://postgis.net/workshops/postgis-intro/geography.html)